# Trying to understand where the menu I get with manim comes from

Tags: python, manim

I'm trying to learn how to use `manim`.  I've been looking at what I believe is the standard [tutorial](https://talkingphysics.wordpress.com/2019/01/08/getting-started-animating-with-manim-and-python-3-7/).  I'm now taking some code from the [documentation](https://manim.readthedocs.io/en/latest/getting_started/learning_by_example.html) of manim (not the tutorial).

The code I'm running is this (taken from the first example, but with the import command added):

```
from manimlib.imports import *

class SquareToCircle(Scene):
    def construct(self):
        circle = Circle()
        square = Square()
        square.flip(RIGHT)
        square.rotate(-3 * TAU / 8)
        circle.set_fill(PINK, opacity=0.5)

        self.play(ShowCreation(square))
        self.play(Transform(square, circle))
        self.play(FadeOut(square))
```

and I'm running it from the command line

> $ manim SquareToCircle.py
>
> Media will be stored in ./media/. You can change this behavior by writing a 
>    different directory to media_dir.txt.
>
> 1: Banner
>
> 2: ComplexTransformationScene
>
> 3: CountInBinaryTo256
>
> 4: CountInDecimal
>
> 5: CountInTernary
>
> 6: CountingScene
>
> 7: DiscreteGraphScene
>
> 8: ExternallyAnimatedScene
>
> 9: FactorialBase
>
> 10: GraphScene
>
> etc
>
> 25: SquareToCircle
>
> etc
>
> Choose number corresponding to desired scene/arguments.
>
> (Use comma separated list for multiple entries)
>
> Choice(s):

When I select 25, it runs and produces the output expected.  But where are all of those other options coming from?  Is there a way to avoid having them show up?

Answer (score 0):

I think the menu shows up because you do not specify which scene you want to render in the command line. You can make multiple scenes in a python file and the name of the scene is what you call your class. Try `$ manim SquareToCircle.py SquareToCircle`.
The menu are scenes in some example file I think.

Comment: I agree they probably come from 'some example file', but why are they showing up here?  For example, nowhere in my code do I have `Banner`, but it's the first option.  What about the code I provided causes `manim` to look up some example file (and what is that file)?

Comment: All these scenes are spread throughout the manim source code, for example, Banner's is in *manimlib/for_3b1b_videos/common_scenes.py*, so you should look for the others.

Answer (score 0):

To see only the scenes that are inside a file, do the following:

1. Open the *manimlib/extract_scene.py* file
2. Replace the `is_child_scene` method, this is the one you should have:

```py
def is_child_scene(obj, module):
    if not inspect.isclass(obj):
        return False
    if not issubclass(obj, Scene):
        return False
    if obj == Scene:
        return False
    return True
```

With this:

```py
def is_child_scene(obj, module):
    if not inspect.isclass(obj):
        return False
    if not issubclass(obj, Scene):
        return False
    if obj == Scene:
        return False
    # Add this conditional
    # |
    # v
    if not obj.__module__.startswith(module.__name__):
        return False
    return True
```

3. Save the changes and try again.

More information about this issue [here](https://github.com/3b1b/manim/commit/4fa782b8b5f16378a8352315b7975581b9fd87fe).